# env specific property resolution in maven build

Tags: java, maven

In our project we have a separate project from configurations. We have 9 envs and each env requires different set of configurations. I am trying to have a single build which can generate config for all the envs. My directory structure is as below

```
src/
  main/
   resources/
    configs/
     windows/
     dev-1/
     dev-2/
     it-1/
     it-2/
     sit-feed/
     sit-marker/
     preprod/
     prod  /
```

each env has a file path-core.conf which has entry like

```
sourcing-board-pu.path = ${ARTIFACT_LOACTION}/lib/sourcing-board-pu.jar
```

each env has file build.properties

```
/src/main/resources/confirs/dev-1/
ARTIFACT_LOACTION=/home/dev/sharedlocation/

/src/main/resources/confirs/prod/
ARTIFACT_LOACTION=/home/prod/sharedlocation/
```

I want ${ARTIFACT_LOACTION} to be replaced by value in properties file in their specific env.

I understand that the correct way might be to create separate profile for each env but is it possible without profile as we do not want to create every time we remove or add an env, it should be something like create env specific files and add that env to list of env? something like this

```
mvn clean install -Denv=dev-1,dev-2,preprod,prod
```

i am also not sure if comma separated properties are supported as a part of maven properties plugin

Comment: you can take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Comment: as per my understanding the above plugin binds me to the name of properties file to just 'first.properties' secondly it creates separate war files for each env, i was planning to have a single zip file with all the configs.

Comment: No it binds you not to the names. you can name them how you like and of course as many files you like......it was just an example (need to improve the docs). And you can of course use a zip/jar files if you like instead.

Comment: If you like having a single file with all the configs you keep the files in the location you have and make a single jar by using packaging jar of it. Without supplemental things. Just use `mvn clean package` ...you should prevent having java code in this package...